# Getting raw display data from NSView

Tags: objective-c, nsview

my goal is to send an NSView over the wire. i was wondering whether there was a way to get the raw display data contained in an NSView so that I can send this data over the wire and re-display this at the destination.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff LaMarche posted a brief tidbit about this on his blog a while ago:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/getting-contents-of-uiview-as-uiimage.html

He links to [this pastie](http://pastie.org/244916) which contains:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myView.bounds.size);
[myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

That will apparently convert `myView` in a `UIImage` called `viewImage` that you can then convert to an `NSData` and transmit how you like.